# Questions with [tag:medical] tag

Tags: support

I found [questions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/medical) tagged as [medical](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/medical), some 12 questions with 1 follower.
This tag has no `info` as I was curious to find out what questions it would cover.

What is the justified use of this tag? I saw a question on Ayurveda which is not relevant to our site. Use of such tag can cause ambiguity? I'm sure not all people who post questions go through the introduction page when they sign up.

All I could do in this case was to vote the question to close on `blatantly off-topic`  I would like to know the purpose of this tag please.

Comment: For the most part, it's a meta tag, but in some cases, there is value in some form of tag.  Medical applications are a specialty, and some form of tag is useful in attracting or filtering answerers.  There is a question or two relating to things like image conversion, and some of those filetypes may be unique to medical equipment, so unfamiliar to most readers.  Dedicated tags for one or two questions aren't useful.  It makes me question whether this is the right place for those questions, whether they should be considered on-topic.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be used as a qualifier when the hardware or software is being used in any kind of medical environment.

It feels very much like a meta-tag. It is only useful when there are other tags or information in the question that tell you what kind of medical software or hardware is being used.

As such I would say for [medical](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/medical) to be removed and replaced with tags that are specific to the hardware or software that the question is asking about.

Comment: Is there an option to remove a tag or is it possible to recommend for the same?

Comment: We cannot simply nuke a tag, they will need to be edited out manually. It looks like a couple of new tags might need to be created in the process as there's at least one question with no other tags at all.